# Appium: Ruby: Distributed tests with appium for iOS

Tags: ios, automation, cucumber, appium, distributed-computing

I am having a fully fledged suite for automated tests written using ruby with Appium for mobile automation.

I am running these suites in one simulator in one machine and it takes up a lot of time, around 1 hour to run 56 test cases(We have system test cases where multiple checks like database/Api/functional are integrated). We have more additional test cases adding to our way.

We have implemented running our tests across 3 mac machines currently with running different cucumber tags integrated to Jenkins. However, more addition of tests is only going to take us more time or more mac's

With xcode 9 we can initiate multiple simulators on one machine at the same time, and I had like to know, if there is any sample scenario or documentation on how to implement distributed tests across simulators in one mac machine

I had tried loading two or three different desired capabilities with different platform version, but it only loads the tests in sequential order.

I had gone through a lot of material online that has only the steps to make this possible in android. Does iOS support it?

Or could anyone possibly provide links that would help me? to
1. Implement distributed tests across various simulators in one mac
2. Use cucumber tags to distribute tests creating instance for each desired capability

**Update:**

I had tried implementing the multithread option and tried to initiate the tests to specific simulator creating instance with each thread. However, I find the tests not running in parallel but sequential.

This is my code:

```
def start_app(device_id, wdalocalport)
    caps_config = {
        platformName: "iOS",
        wdaLocalPort: wdalocalport,
        deviceName: "iPhone Simulator", #update device as per your need
        app: (File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Sequoia.app")),
        bundleId: "something",
        automationName: "XCUITest",
        xcodeOrgId: "something",
        xcodeSigningId: "iPhone Developer",
        #platformVersion: "10.2",
        noReset: "true",
        fullReset: "false",
        showIOSLog: "true",
        autoAcceptAlerts: "true",
        showXcodeLog: "true",
        useNewWDA: "true",
        resetOnSessionStartOnly: "true",
        udid: device_id }
    appium_lib_config={ port: 4723 }
    $opts={ caps: caps_config, appium_lib: appium_lib_config }
    setup

  end


  def setup
    @appium = Appium::Driver.new($opts)
    @appium.start_driver

    #Makes all appium_lib methods accessible from steps
    #Starts appium driver before the tests begin

  end


  def test(device1,device2)
    threads = []
    threads << Thread.new {
      start_app(device1, '8100')




    }
    threads << Thread.new {
      start_app(device2, '8200')



    }
    threads.each(&:join)

  end
end
```

I am calling the launch tests using the `test` method passing the `udid's`. The simulators launch at the same time, and also installs the application at the same time, but the tests aren't parallel.

Any help to improvise this case?

I was able to use the `rake` to parallel run, but I still find this approach runs the tests in sequential manner or doesnt run at all

PFB the code

```
def run_cucumber(cucumber_options)
  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new do |t|
    t.cucumber_opts = cucumber_options
  end
  Rake::Task[:cucumber].invoke
end




task :iphone_7 do |t|
  ENV['DEVICE'] = 'iphone7'
  run_cucumber('-r features features/test.feature --format pretty --tags @slave1')
end

task :iphone_8 do |t|
  ENV['DEVICE'] = 'iphone8'
  run_cucumber('-r features features/test.feature --format pretty --tags @slave2')
end

multitask :all => [:iphone_7,:iphone_8]
```

My `hooks.rb`

```
Before do
  check
end
def check
  if ENV['DEVICE'] == 'iphone7'
    start_app('iPhone6','port','udid')
  elsif ENV['DEVICE'] == 'iphone8'
    start_app('iphone6','port','udid')
  else
    puts "Device not"
  end
end
```

I have been getting `DEVICE NOT`. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: you can distribute the tests using multithreading + asynchronous execution, but to do that, need to see if your framework supports that. if you are interested, I can help you out.

Comment: @PankajKumarKatiyar I had like your help. I am using cucumber framework with my tests written in ruby and gherkin. We are using appium for our mobile tests.

Comment: I tried using two set of different capabilities with different platform version and implemented the thread to have instance for each

 ```threads = []
  [device1, device2].each do |capability|
    threads << Thread.new do
      # RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
      TestParallelRun.new(capability).test_run
    end
  end

  threads.each(&:join)`` 

This threw errors to me...

Comment: @PankajKumarKatiyar I would be glad if you help me out with the implementation :) Please let me know the best way to get connected to you? since stackoverflow does not allow a lot of comments

Comment: @PankajKumarKatiyar I have tried launching the simulators implementing the multithreading concept. But, the behaviour is something which Is not expected. I beleive it needs few tweeks, Please let me know in case your online and your inputs could help me

Comment: you should launch simulators + connect to driver in one thread, which language you are using ?

Comment: I am using ruby. Currently, when i run tests, both simulators are launching but only one is running the tests and if it fails, only then the other simulator starts, installs the webdriver agent and quits

Comment: Are you running appium on different ports and assign each port to a driver ?

Comment: No! I m using a single port, since appium 1.7.0 doesnt need to be run on two ports to launch two simulators as it supports it?

Comment: how do you divide traffic then? why don't you try with two different ports and attach driver to these.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156278/discussion-between-mrityunjeyan-s-and-pankaj-kumar-katiyar).

Comment: I have continued my update in the chat, please switch to chat mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a method which invokes cucumber rake first in the Rakefile as follows:

```
def run_cucumber(cucumber_options)
  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new do |t|
    t.cucumber_opts = cucumber_options
  end
  Rake::Task[:cucumber].invoke
end
```

This method will need cucumber_options. You can pass same options as you pass on the command line like this:

```
-r features features/test.feature --format pretty --tags @test1
```

After this, define rake tasks for a particular configuration in the same Rakefile:

```
task :iphone_7 do |t|
  ENV["DEVICE"] = "iphone 7"
  run_cucumber('-r features features/test.feature --format pretty --tags @test1')
end

task :iphone_8 do |t|
  ENV["DEVICE"] = "iphone 8"
  run_cucumber('-r features features/test.feature --format pretty --tags @test2')
end
```

Here, ENV["DEVICE"] is used set to device config. You can use this variable in your env.rb in Before block to initialize the test. In Before block you can initialize devices based on this environment variable.

You can create rake tasks like this as many as you need.

Then you can invoke multiple tasks at the same time by using ruby's parallel gem. Examples are in this link -> [Ruby Parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)
Just pass different types of rake task as the arguments in the Parallel object.
Eg:

```
task :run_parallel do |t|
  Parallel.map([:iphone_7,:iphone_8]) {|task| Rake::Task[task].invoke } 
end
```

And then trigger the run_parallel rake task to execute the whole code. 
Eg:

```
bundle exec rake run_parallel
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will check on this, and update you in half hour

Comment: Hey! Meanwhile this morning, i was trying to implement the parallel tests with the multi thread and I have updated the question. Can you take a look at that?>

Also, I am quite not clear on the `rake` implementation as I got no clue on that. I understand the `cucumber_options` but couldn't much on the `ENV["DEVICE"] = "iphone6" .

Do you mean to say I use `ENV["DEVICE"] == iphone6, if condition in `before` hooks and load the `desired capabilities` which I have tagged to that particular ENV?

Comment: Is there anyway we can connect so that I can understand this better as I go through from you? Skype or slack or hangout?

Comment: Yes, you can check this condition in before hooks and load the desired capabilities.
You can learn from this on how to write a rake task -> http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/rake/

Create rake file in your project and write this code and then create a new rake task for parallelizing them.
Then you just need to run that rake task.

Comment: I did create a rake file, but I am still not able to understand the  implementation of the `parallel` gem. I had mentioned the code I implemented in the question. Could you please take a look

Comment: Hey! Could you please check the code above, in the question and suggest me ?

Comment: Now create a new rake say `run_parallel` then write code to trigger the rake tasks[eg: iphone_7, iphone_8] parallelly in this method.
Eg:
`def run_parallel
    Parallel.map([:iphone_7,:iphone_8]) {|task| Rake::Task[task].invoke }
end
`
And then trigger the `run_parallel` rake task to execute the whole code. Eg: `bundle exec rake run_parallel`

Comment: Thanks @OarpitO . Thanks a lot really, for the help :)